# How to search records from a table with composite key in EF6?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've created my database schema using Entity Framework's Code First, and one of the models has a composite key (which is reflected perfectly in the db).

However, when I try to look for records using a list of composite keys I get an exception that says:
"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

This is the code I've used last that failed (variations of this had also produced the same error):

```
var ids = models.Select(m => new { m.Id, m.InstanceId })
                .ToArray();

var records = _dataService.TableWithCompositeKey
                          .Where(t => ids.Contains(new { t.Id, t.InstanceId }))
                          .ToArray();
```

The exception is thrown when evaluating records. So how can I accomplish such a task ?

Comment: How many items will `ids` typically contain? The problem is, you can only use `Contains` with primitive data types. If you want similar behavior you can either build expressions (but that will overflow when there are "many" ids) or do the comparison in memory.

Comment: Well, there might be more than a few ids.. 
The problem is that it's not that intuitive like a single key and it might make me change the query so it won't be optimized (for example multiple queries and not just one) or even change the schema..

Comment: You could do a query with two `Contains` statements (for `Id`s and `InstanceId`s separately), which will provide a first coarse database-side filtering, and subsequently in memory do the final filtering to make sure that the pairs match.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT : Rename variable, and add comments on multiple records**
I did assume you wanted single records on after the other due to the nature of this problem. Contains cant do what you want in EF.

`Context.Set<poco>.Find()` supports multiple field keys
see Ef Source   `public virtual TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues)`

```
var record = _dataService.TableWithCompositeKey
                         .Find( Id, InstanceId )
                         .ToList();
```

if you can NOT  get teh records with a regular where clause and remove the unwanted entries not in the key list then :

a)  Get individually
    foreach...
          find(a,b)

b) Build the where clause dynamically
   using something like Predicate builder see below, to build the where clause
   with 
   foreach
      Thischeck =  ( a = X and b = Y )  // eg create Expression for (Tpoco t)=>value.Equals(t.PropertyName) 
      Whereclause.Or(thisCheck)

**observation,** If you have small number of entries to collect, then individual gets is of consideration.
If you have many records to get, then size of the Where clause generated is of consideration.  That may end up with a full table scan of the DB.

You also need to be careful that the Linq you generate doesnt cause all records to be loaded into memory before the wanted records are found.

No nice solution to this issue.

```
/// See http://www.albahari.com/expressions for information and examples.
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T> () { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T> () { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                              Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
             (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                               Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
             (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Find() method returns a single entity, not multiple.